# Ubuntu Budgie: How to use Alt+Shift to switch keyboard layouts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, budgie

I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu Budgie and I can't get <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch keyboard layouts. I write articles almost every day using English and Greek and it's pretty annoying to change the language using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Is there a way to switch keyboard layouts using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Ubuntu Budgie 17.04, you would have noticed that using the GUI Settings - Keyboard - Typing - Switch to Input Source does not respond to a <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> by itself.  You need a third keystroke.

However you can go behind the scenes and install the package `dconf-editor` and edit one or both of the following keys to get things working:

Go to `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`

change switch-input-source to `['<Alt>Shift_L']`

Likewise the key switch-input-source-backward change to `['<Shift>Alt_L']`

Comment: BTW, you must run it from your user not from root (sudo -i).

Offtopic for devs: OMG! 2017 year. Gnome & Budgie and others Developers, please make "ALT SHIFT" GREAT AGAIN! Why i need do this stuff every time when i reinstall the system. Its very annoing! Plssssss. And make a shortcut into "Regional and Language settings" to chose this keys....

Comment: O God, thanks! In my case I used to ['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Shift>Alt_L'] combination for switch-input-source, and switch-input-source-backward is empty. So I use only two languages.

Answer (score 2):

Because I like commmand line (fast) solutions, I tried the above gsettings command, but had to modify it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, it is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (same as on MacOS X). You can run this terminal command to change it.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['&lt;Alt&gt;Shift_L', '&lt;Super&gt;Shift_L']"
```